# Add more delegate protocols in view using XCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, delegates, protocols

```
@interface WinesViewController : UITableViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *sortedObjects;
}
```

In the code above, the UIActionSheetDelegate protocol is added because I use an UIActionSheet to sort the TableView and it needed a delegate.
Now I'm adding a SwipeGestureRecognizer in the DetailViewController to access the next cell in the TableView from the Detail View. The tutorial I'm using is telling me to add a delegate protocol for the DetailViewController in the TableViewController. And it's telling me to add it in the exact same way as I've already added the UIActionSheetDelegate, so how to add a delegate for the DetailViewController now?

Comment: Multiple protocols are separated by Commas as @Stretch mentioned below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just add it into the same place as the `UIActionSheetDelegate`, seperated with a comma:

```
@interface WinesViewController : UITableViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, DetailViewControllerDelegate> {
NSMutableArray *sortedObjects;
}
```

(replace `DetailViewControllerDelegate` with the delegate name you need to add.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also worth noting is that you can amend the list of adopted protocols in a category or class continuation.